# android, why after covert to kotlin the unit test fail

Tags: kotlin, mockito, android-unit-testing

On android app, Having a java function

```
JSONObject addToJson(@NonNull JSONObject jsonObject, @NonNull String key, boolean value){
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, value);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

test code, it throws when call the mock jsonObject.put(key, value) and works fine:

```
    @Test
    public void test_addToJson() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = Mockito.spy(new JSONObject());
        Mockito.when(jsonObject.put(anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenThrow(new JSONException("!!! test forced exception"));
        JSONObject outputObject = addToJson(jsonObject, "null", true);
        assertEquals("jsonobject length should match", 0, outputObject.length());
    }
```

after convert to kotlin

```
    fun addToJson(jsonObject: JSONObject, key: String, value: Boolean?): JSONObject {
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, value)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {         
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return jsonObject
    }
```

the test is failing that no exception thrown.

Comment: A `Boolean?` corresponds to `@Nullable Boolean` in Java, so `anyBoolean` might not be the correct matcher.

Comment: In this case it might be an incorrect translation from Java to Kotlin. The Java code used the primitive `boolean` which can't be `null`, so `Boolean` without the `?` ought to work in the Kotlin code. If you still want it to be nullable, then perhaps you can use the `anyOrNull` matcher from mockito-kotlin.

Comment: @Michael, you are right. the kotlin code maps the jsonObject.put(key, value) to `JSONObject put(@NonNull String name, @Nullable Object value)` when it sees the  value: Boolean?.  If you put in as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java code uses the primitive type `boolean` for `value`. The Kotlin version is using the nullable type `Boolean?` which seems unnecessary since the parameter could never be `null` in the Java version.

The change to a nullable type might cause the `anyBoolean` matcher to fail. You could try switching to the non-nullable type `Boolean`, or keep using `Boolean?` and change the `anyBoolean` matcher to `anyOrNull` from mockito-kotlin.